# Woocommerce cart is not clear after logout

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am implementing an LMS using one plus theme,learndash and woocommerce plugins. Currently when a user log out, his cart persist and the item in his cart can be edited by a guest user.I want to clear the cart after a user logout from his account.I tried the answer, given in this link for fixing the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/32785631/6270441. I tried putting this code in my themes function.php,but it is not working.

```
function your_function() {
    if( function_exists('WC') ){
        WC()->cart->empty_cart();
    }
}
add_action('wp_logout', 'your_function');
```

Comment: Are you using any caching plugin in your site?

Comment: no I am not using any caching plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code by using global `$woocommerce`

```
add_action( 'wp_logout', 'force_clear_woocommerce_cart' );
function force_clear_woocommerce_cart() 
{

    error_log("Clearing cart");
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

}
```

hope this will help you

Comment: well I tried. no changes.In localhost no issues like this.when I hosted the site this problem appeared, and no additional codes i added  in functions.php is working.

Comment: Thanks for responding.But how to set user id?

Comment: move the add_action below the function

Comment: and check it is working or not

Comment: i've tried to implement this solution on my website, but it doesn't work and I really can't understand the reason. Do you have any suggestion?